# Python in function not finding string in tuple?

Tags: python, intersection

```
def bestInvitation(first, second):
    yeah=tuple(zip(first, second))
    res=list(set.intersection(*map(set, yeah)))
    common=str(res)
    count=0
    for i in yeah:
        if common in i:
            count+=1
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(bestInvitation(["fishing", "gardening", "swimming", "fishing"], 
                         ["hunting", "fishing", "fishing", "biting"]))
```

In the code above, line 6 should find the number of times that the common element between the 4 pairs of activities. This example should return 4 because fishing is a common element which occurs 4 times. However, it is returning 0. I think it's because common is not just a string, but a list of one string, but I don't know how to turn res into just a string. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `print` statement makes the problem clear:

```
...
for i in yeah:
    print(common, i)
    if common in i:
...
```

Output:

```
['fishing'] ('fishing', 'hunting')
['fishing'] ('gardening', 'fishing')
['fishing'] ('swimming', 'fishing')
['fishing'] ('fishing', 'biting')
```

You did *not* search for a string in a tuple of strings: you search for a string *image* of a list *containing* a string within your tuple.  Since there is no such entity inside your tuple, the `if` statement fails on every iteration.

Fix your data handling -- one line:

```
common=str(res[0])
```

Now you get the desired output of `4`.